# Why does this sentence use "which" without a comma before it (instead of ", which"), and what's the difference?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

I'm trying to understand this sentence. I have set the "which" in bold:

> If you start a container **which** creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume.

Why doesn't this sentence use a comma before "which" (i.e. "[...] container, which creates [...]")?

When should I use a comma before "which", and what's the difference?

Comment: Because "which creates a new volume" is an integral part describing a particular container type (a container with a volume), you can't left it out.

Comment: The grammar you're looking for is *defining relative clause* (or *identifying relative clause*) vs *non-defining relative clause* (or *non-identifying relative clause*). There's tons of info about this on the Internet.

Answer (score 5):

Because in English, a *restrictive relative clause* (one that contributes to specifying the noun phrase it is attached to) is not set off as a separate breath group, and so is not written with a comma.

Here *which creates a new volume* is not an incidental comment about the container,  but is specifying the container, so it is a restrictive clause.

Answer (score 3):

You have possibly been taught that 'which' introduces a non-restrictive clause and should always be preceded by a comma, while 'that' introduces a restrictive clause and does not have a comma.

By that rule, your example should use 'that' and omit the comma, as it is identifying or defining the kind of container being spoken about.

[Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-that-and-which) notes that, in modern English, 'which' can introduce either kind of clause, suggesting that the 'rule' is no longer followed, but grammar nuts may disagree. Personally, I like to follow the rule in written English.

Comment: I think the use of "which" (without commas) to introduce a restrictive clause is also more common in British English than in American English.